# C# How can I check if today is the first Monday of the month?

Tags: c#, date

How can I check if today is the first Monday of the month?

The code below gives me the last day of the month, how should I modify this?

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(
       today.Year, 
       today.Month, 
       DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, today.Month)
);
```

Comment: Probably easier just to look on a calendar

Answer (score 54, accepted):

How about:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday && today.Day <= 7)
```

*Finding* the first Monday of the month is slightly trickier. It's not clear whether or not you need that - let us know if you need that.

Note the use of `DateTime.Today` *once* - that way you don't end up with potential oddities where the date changes between the two parts of the condition being evaluated.

Comment: Your last paragraph begs the question of "If the day changes during computation, should you ever return true?"

Comment: @glowcoder: I think it's reasonable if *either* the "old day" *or* the "new day" is the first Monday. It's unreasonable if *neither* of them is actually the first Monday of the month.

Comment: certainly agree on the second statement, no question. The first statement took some mulling over. I'm still in the air about it, but I suppose it's *reasonable* (in that you can make the case for it, and we have no specific reason to exclude it.)

Comment: @glowcoder: Put it this way - how could you ever do anything better than the first approach? You've got a race condition effectively. Imagine it's the first Monday of the month when you evaluate the condition, but then it ticks over to Tuesday by the time you get to *act* on that information... how is that any different? I don't think there's any sensible way of avoiding that sort of race.

Comment: that makes more sense. You'd need a second validation, which itself is susceptible to the exact same problem, which forces a third, which is sus... and so on... It forced the question, and the question was answered. Thanks for clearing it up!

Answer (score 22):

```
bool isItFirstMonday = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday 
                         && DateTime.Today.Day <= 7
```

Edit: sorry, typo :)

Comment: `DaysOfTheWeek` should be `DayOfWeek`. but +1

Comment: IMO it's a bad idea to evaluated DateTime.Today twice. Imagine it's coming up to midnight on the last day of the month, which is a Monday. The first part of the condition is evaluated and returns "true" (because it's Monday). Then midnight hits, and it's Tuesday 1st of the next month... so the second part returns "true" too... despite the fact that neither the "old" day nor the "new" day is the first Monday of the month.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: sorry, I typed fast, and forgot to stop for that one microsecond during the 168 hours of a week, but of course you're right!

Answer (score 8):

I don't know c#, but in any language, it's

```
if Today is monday, 
and Today's Date is 7 or less.
```

Answer (score 4):

A related case is, as Jon said, slightly trickier. Presuming you know the year and month:

```
public static DateTime getFirstMondayOfMonthAndYear(int Month, int Year)
{
    DateTime dt;
    DateTime.TryParse(String.Format("{0}/{1}/1", Year, Month), out dt); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
        if (dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
        {
            return dt;
        }
        else
        {
            dt = dt.AddDays(1);
        }
        }
    // If get to here, punt
    return DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: Using `TryParse`, without giving format provider (culture), can be dangerous and is unnecessary here. Returning a wrong value in the impossible case is a bad idea; `throw` an exception instead. If you want to solve it by running through the seven possibilities, you can also say `return Enumerable.Range(1, 7).Select(i => new DateTime(Year, Month, i)).First(d => d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday);`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following

```
DateTime dt = ...;
if (dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday && dt.Day <= 7) {
  // First Monday of the month
}
```