# ASP.NET Getting working weeks for every month

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, .net-2.0

I have a form that accept input of 'Month' and 'Year', I am writing here to ask any idea on how will I get all 'working weeks'?

I mean 'Working weeks' as Monday - Friday

So basically I need week1 to week4 or if available including week5.

For example if I input January 2013:

```
week1 = January 1 to January 4
week2 = January 7 to January 11
week3 = January 14 to January 18
week4 = January 21 to January 25
week5 = January 28 to January 31
```

How can I achieve that? Thanks for any help! Any suggestions or ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thanks mates! :)

Comment: which version of .net are you using?

Comment: I used .net 2.0, because Im creating a single page that will be uploaded to sharepoint, and the sharepoint only support 2.0 :(

Comment: So what happens is someone enters a month and a year, then the user gets an output of all standard working days of that month in that year?

Comment: No, After the user input month and year I need to get week1-week5, so I can use it with my select command with my sql query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this Linq query:

```
int month = 1;
int year = 2013;
var cal = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
IEnumerable<int> daysInMonth = Enumerable.Range(1, cal.GetDaysInMonth(year, month));

List<Tuple<int, DateTime, DateTime>> listOfWorkWeeks = daysInMonth
    .Select(day => new DateTime(year, month, day))
    .GroupBy(d => cal.GetWeekOfYear(d, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday))
    .Select(g => Tuple.Create(g.Key, g.First(), g.Last(d => d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)))
    .ToList();

// Item1 = week in year, Item2 = first day, Item3 = last working day
int weekNum = 1;
foreach (var weekGroup in listOfWorkWeeks)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Week{0} = {1} {2} to {1} {3}"
        , weekNum++
        , System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(month)
        , weekGroup.Item2.Day
        , weekGroup.Item3.Day);
}
```

output for January:

```
Week1 = January 1 to January 4
Week2 = January 7 to January 11
Week3 = January 14 to January 18
Week4 = January 21 to January 25
Week5 = January 28 to January 31
```

and for February:

```
Week1 = February 1 to February 1
Week2 = February 4 to February 8
Week3 = February 11 to February 15
Week4 = February 18 to February 22
Week5 = February 25 to February 28
```

Comment: The name 'CalendarWeekRule' does not exist in the current content. :(

Comment: Add a using for `System.Globalization`.

Comment: @JRC: If you don't want to use an additional variable to increment the week number, you can replace  `Tuple.Item1` (which is currently the weeknumber  in year) with index+1 of that group: `.Select((g, i) => Tuple.Create(i+1, g.First(), g.Last(d => d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)))`. Then you can use `weekGroup.Item1` as first parameter in `Console.WriteLine`.

Answer (score 0):

Find the first Monday of the month and year.

```
int year = 2013;
int month = 1;

DateTime testDate = new DateTime(year,month,1);


while ( testDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday )
{
   testDate = testDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

Then iterate over each week until you reach a year that isn't 2013.

```
// Should have first monday now.
// Loop until the month changes
while ( testDate.Month == month)
{
   var monday = testDate;
   var friday = testDate.AddDays(4);

   // You now have both dates.  Do whatever you need to.
   // here.

   // Increment test date by a week
   testDate = testDate.AddDays(7)
}
```

Comment: this is a terrible solution - looping is madness

Comment: @Dave Bish - Put a better answer up.  We're all scientists here.  I love to see refinement.

Comment: @jgauffin - Depends on how the user wants to roll the years.  Is week 52 of 2012 the last week of 2012 or the first week of 2013.

Comment: Still waiting for the non-loop solution, @DaveBish :)  Those four/five iterations are looking rather inexpensive at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code:

1. Start from the first day of the month
2. While (day != Monday) take next date (+1 day)

   See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170822/c-sharp-how-can-i-check-if-today-is-the-first-monday-of-the-month) (Jon Skeet answer!) for checking if a day is a Monday.
3. Add 4 days to find the end of the working week

   If it's in the same month, than you have a working week for your answer.
4. Add 7 days to find the next Monday
5. If the new Monday is still within the same month: repeat 3. and 4.

**EDIT** The above finds all *complete* working weeks.

To find the other weeks as well:

- If the first day of the month is already a working day, find the next Friday. -> 1st working week
- If the last friday is in the next month, finish the last working week at the last day of the month. -> last working week